# How to remove start and end html tag using C#?

Tags: c#, html, .net, tags

If I have some html code, like:

```
<p>Some text</p><p>More text</p>
```

...and I want to remove the start and end tags of that string, so I end up with:

```
Some text</p><p>More text
```

What would the C# code look like? I want it to work with any tag type, if they have classes, etc. Just need to be able to remove the start and end tags.

Comment: Playing around with `Substring()` and `IndexOf()` you can do it, `IndexOf(">")` and `LastIndexOf("</")` to know where to start and end positions are for the `Substring()`. The lenght of the substring would be the difference of those values. You can check the string related methods in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Regex

```
var item = "<p>Some text</p><p>More text</p>";
item = Regex.Replace(item,@"^<[^>^<.]*>","");
item = Regex.Replace(item,@"<[^>^<.]*>$","");
Console.WriteLine(item) //Will log Some text</p><p>More text
```

Regex Breakdown:

`^`: matches start of string

`<`: opening tag

`>`: closing tag

`[^>^<.]*`: exclude closing and opening tags inside tag and match any character except the excluded ones as often as possible

Do the same again just this time we match the end of the string with `$`at the end of the expression

Comment: works great, thx

Answer (score 0):

If the tags are always 3 chars u just remove the first and last 3 chars from the string. If you want to use this you can try string.Remove(0,2); for example.
string.replace won't work because the string contains multiple

and you don't want them all removed.

Edit: I see you want it to work with any tag type, then I would try this: Find the first > and the last < in the string. And use those positions with 0 and string.length to string.remove the tags.

Comment: no I don't know that, as I said they could be any tag type, have attributes, etc

Comment: @E.D. Check my comment on your question

Comment: @Cleptus Nice, I didn't know of LastIndexOf("</"). Also learned something today ;)